# Obj-C: Accept a block body as a method argument

Tags: objective-c, block

New at Obj-C and I'm trying to understand how I can accept a block from a method argument and pass to another method.

So, lets say I've got a basic object (inheriting from NSObject) that can load data from JSON. It has a method like this:

```
- (void)loadDataFromJSON
{
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [http requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:MY_PATH parameters:MY_PARAMS];

  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
  [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                  success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                    NSLog(@"success: %@",JSON);
                                                  }
                                                  failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                    NSLog(@"failure: %@",JSON);
                                                  }];

}
```

Now, if I use this object in a View Controller I want to have it load its data, and then I want to view it, only after the data has loaded. What I'd like to do is take success and failure blocks as arguments for the `loadDataFromJSON` method and pass them to the `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure` call, but I don't understand the syntax for doing this.

I tried:

```
- (void)loadDataFromJSONWithSuccess:(^)successBlock failure:(^)failureBlock;
```

This doesn't work, with XCode saying it expects a type. So how do I tell it the type is a block to be passed along to `JSONRequestOpertation...` ?

Comment: Agreed, thanks Josh. +1 vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)loadDataFromJSONWithSuccess:(void(^)())successBlock failure:(void(^)())failureBlock;
```